# javascript - Altering w3 example table filter to support multiple text inputs

Tags: javascript, php

I am learning PHP, and I am still very far, far away from understanding javascript. I need help understanding how to filter an HTML table with a javascript. Here is a brief description of what I am doing.

I am getting a list of URLs and Titles into the array.

```
    $html_results[$html_int][0] = $link->getAttribute('href');
    $html_results[$html_int][1] = $link->nodeValue;
```

To print these results, I use a function to build the table.

```
 function build_table($html_results){
    echo '<table id="urlTable">';
    echo '<tr class="header">';
    echo '<th style="width:70%;">URL</th>';
    echo '<th style="width:40%;">TITLE</th>';
    echo '</tr>';

    for($i=0;$i<count($html_results);$i++) {
      echo('<tr>');
      echo('<td>' . $html_results[$i][0] . '</td>');
      echo('<td>' . $html_results[$i][1] . '</td>');
      echo('</tr>');
    }
    "</table>";
```

This works very well, but now I need to filter these results without reloading the page. I created two text fields, like in the example below:

```
input type="text" id="URLFilter" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Filter URLs.."
input type="text" id="TitleFilter" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Filter Titles.."
```

I tried using this function from w3schools:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("URLFilter");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("urlTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
</script>
```

And this script works well. I can filter the table, but it works only for the first column in the table, and for the URLFilter input. What I need help understanding is how can I modify this function to:

- Filter the first column in the table with URLFilter input. The script should DISPLAY rows that contain URLFilter
- Filter the second column in the table with TitleFilter input. The script should HIDE rows that contain TitleFilter
- Use both filters at the same time without reloading the table

I don't mind if I need to call two separate scripts to make it work. I tried making two scripts, but the table always resets and does not combine two filters. I also need a way to store results from a filtered table into another PHP array, that I would like to save into the database. Please apologize for the long post, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To combine the filter you need to apply both filters if you change the value of `URLFilter` or `TitleFilter` so you will only need 1 function. The code below compares both input values and if 1 of them doesn't match the row is hidden.

```
function myFunction() {
  var url = document.getElementById("URLFilter").value,
      title = document.getElementById("TitleFilter").value,
      table = document.getElementById("urlTable"),
      matchURL = true,
      matchTitle = true;

  for(var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) { // loop over table rows
    table.rows[i].style.display = ''; // show row

    matchURL = (url == '' || table.rows[i].cells[0].innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(url) > -1);
    matchTitle = (title == '' || table.rows[i].cells[1].innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(title) > -1);

    if(!matchURL || !matchTitle) {
      table.rows[i].style.display = 'none'; // hide row
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Dehart - I had to change your code a little bit. Instead of comparing both values (and if one of them does not match, hide it), I compare each input value in separate if statements. It now works perfectly! Thank you! I will mark this as an answer!